# Alternatives to calling ping executable from Java on Android

Tags: android, command, ping

I am using the following code to call android equipment ping command:

```
public static String pingServer() {
PingResult result = new PingResult();
String jsonString = null;
try {
String command = "ping -c 3 192.168.8.185"; 
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
int status = p.waitFor();
InputStream input = p.getInputStream(); 
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
buffer.append(line);
buffer.append("\n");
}


String bufferStr = buffer.toString();
        System.out.println(bufferStr);

} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("---------------exception-----------ping");
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
// e.printStackTrace();

}
}
```

BufferStr always obtain the last line data.

3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms

The details result can be get.
[image]

Comment: that's real nice and all, but, what was your question again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be simpler and easier to use [InetAddress.isReachable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29):

```
if (InetAddress.getByName("192.168.8.185").isReachable(6000))
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i want to know the result details after ping. not see if it ping success.

Comment: Which details? Ping maybe can only return you the response time in addition.